# How to open an activity from BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom nav view in my android app and i want to open an activity from the click of **Trade** option.
[image]

I googled a lot for this but i can't get expected result. so please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a `bottomsheet` or `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: amm sorry its BottomNavigationView

Comment: yes i will check your answer